# scope.$watch takes a boolean parameter

Tags: angularjs

I have this code

```
scope.$watch('settings.viewType', function() {
                    ...
                }, true);
```

My question is, what is the purpose of the boolean that the watch method takes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a deep watch (check that any property / subproperty of the settings.ViewType changes), only use this if it's needed it can impact performance.

More info:

http://teropa.info/blog/2014/01/26/the-three-watch-depths-of-angularjs.html

Answer (score 1):

From doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

> When objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is determined according to the angular.equals function. To save the value of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used. This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse memory and performance implication